# Android Test testPreconditions

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-testing

In Android developers I've seen that testPreconditions() method is supposed to be launch before all tests. But in my app test, it's acting like a normal test. It does not run before all tests. Is there something wrong ?

Here is the description about testPreconditions() from android developer :
"A preconditions test checks the initial application conditions prior to executing other tests. It's similar to setUp(), but with less overhead, since it only runs once."

Comment: According to Android's tutorial (http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_test.html#AddPreConditionsTest), it is testPreConditions with an uppercase C.

Comment: Case does not matter.  Neither testPreconditions() nor testPreConditions() is guaranteed to run in any given order.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, testPreconditions() is just another unit test.  Here is a quote from "Android Application Testing Guide", a book by Diego Torres Milano:

"**The testPreconditions method** This method is used to check for some initial conditions to run our tests correctly. Despite its name, it is not guaranteed that this test is run before other tests. However, it is a good practice to collect all of the precondition tests under this custom name."

Milano, Diego Torres (2011-06-23). Android Application Testing Guide (p. 76). Packt Publishing. Kindle Edition.

Comment: Why is it considered a good practice if it is not guaranteed to run before other tests?  I could understand if this were the 1st test run after setup(), but as it is it really makes no difference as I might fail all my tests before the precondition test ever gets run.  Five Monkeys?  http://johnstepper.com/2013/10/26/the-five-monkeys-experiment-with-a-new-lesson/

Comment: @BillMote It is simply a convention that helps you troubleshoot failed tests more quickly. If the testPreconditions fail along with several tests in that test class, you'll be able to ignore the other test failures and focus on why the preconditions were not met. See http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_test.html#TestFailure

Comment: I read the developer site and this post.  I understand your point.  I'm just not sure I agree with either assertion that "it's a good practice", however, I wouldn't call it a bad practice either.  LOL

Comment: Fair enough. Perhaps you'd agree that test names should reveal their intent. I often name my tests testSomeActionShouldProduceSomeResult. That way the test explains itself. In the case of a test named testPreconditions, it simply verifies the necessary preconditions for all of the tests. If that test fails, it is evident what I need to investigate and resolve. Simply a naming convention. Like you, I first thought it would execute first, but it turns out to be just like any test, but with a name that follows an intention revealing convention.

Comment: I can get on board for that I guess.

Answer (score 1):

According to Android SDK samples:

> ```
>    The name 'test preconditions' is a convention to signal that if this
>    test doesn't pass, the test case was not set up properly and it might
>    explain any and all failures in other tests.  This is not guaranteed
>    to run before other tests, as junit uses reflection to find the tests.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're inheriting from the right class (ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2), and that your method signature matches:

```
public void testPreconditions()
```